# getObjectsResult.objects led to error

Tags: ios

With QuickBlox, one can create custom objects. All went fine but now I want to display the returned records from one of my custom class. I can see that the records are returned but I cannot grab them to display on a UITableView. I tried saving the result of  getObjectsResult.objects into a NSMutableArray and then used an "objectForKey" construction but although the records were saved in my array, I got the error :

2013-04-25 22:09:09.700 People[897:12b03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[QBCOCustomObject objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x86c2520'

I will appreciate any help to help me fix this. For more check out http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-ios.

Thanks!
-kisimi

Answer (score 0):

For predefine custom object table field, you don't need to use "objectForKey" to get value from field. you need to only use QBCOCustomObject's property for example below...

For getting message ID just use [[QBCOCustomObject]ID].
and for custom filed value [[QBCOCustomObject]objectForKey:@"customFieldName"].